# Где взять адекватный русско-английский словарь?

Tags: поиск-программ, перевод

Я хочу подгружать jquery или даже подделывать headers, но яндекс просит API-key, а Google хочет 20$.

Поискал, но не нашёл оригинальных решений.

Не ужели эти киты не выдержали элементарных запросов пользователей и закрылись, а больше никто и не способен такой сервис предоставить?

У меня на полочке стоит словарь англо-русский, грамм 300 весит, мне больше и не надо. Не ужели это так тяжело для цифровых технологий нашего времени?

Поэтому, спрашиваю у Вас, как сделать переводчик, пускай даже локально? Где взять словарь?

Comment: Где-где взять, сами оцифруйте. Никто для вас специально бесплатно не оцифрует и права на использование не подарит.

Comment: ты чо чурбан? Сколько время? А не кажется ли тебе, дядя-сделай-всё -сам, что уже пора бы понимать, что любые знания человечества давным давно в цифре висят в сети? И такой упрёк - сравним с высказыванием: "Человечество ещё не достигло того уровня сингулярности, что бы иметь все словари для перевода с одного языка на другой - в цифровом виде"?

Comment: Вы, судя по всему, почему-то предполагаете, что все нужные данные висят для вас в интернете бесплатно, и вам нужно лишь прийти и взять их. Технически оцифровать словарь возможно, за деньги. У того, кто может оплатить работу, нужный уровень сингулярности уже достигнут.

Comment: да ты чурбан. я сам отвечу на свой вопрос - когда найду англо-русский словарь в какой-нибудь википедии, и зачту этот вопрос, и он потом - кому-нибудь руско-язычному принесёт пользу, а ты иди лесом, если просто побазарить хочешь, а ничего дельного предложить не можешь.

Comment: Мне не кажется, что с таким отношением к участникам сайта вы можете смело рассчитывать на их внимание к вашим проблемам. Впрочем, желаю удачи.

Comment: http://lingvodics.com/dics/view/English+Russian

Comment: Если нужен словарь, а не переводчик, то их много. Насчет jQuery врятли. Бэкэнд надо какой-то написать который будет дергать  stardict или goldendict

Comment: @VladD всё уже отцифрованно и бесплатно лежит в опенсорсе.

Comment: @eri: до чего дошёл прогресс! По лицензии, однако же, «только некоммерческое использование».

Comment: я что-то не вижу в вопросе "коммерческое использование"

Answer (score 3):

Хотите использовать API перевода Google/Яндекс сверх установленных бесплатных лимитов - извольте оплачивать эти услуги.

На перевод тратятся машинные ресурсы вышеуказанны компаний, причем очень не малые. Обычно эти затраты покрываются прибылью с рекламы. В случае же с API потребление ресурсов гораздо выше чем в браузере/на мобильных устройствах, однако никакой прибыли с этого нет. Поэтому логично брать за использование API некоторую сумму.

У данных компаний нет никакого долга предоставлять вам эти ресурсы беслпатно.

Comment: хаа, какой вопрос - такой ответ, да?

Comment: Яндекс и Гугл апи перевода предоставляют, а ему просто словарик скачать надо... Молодежь не помнит Мэджик Гудди - им все апи подавай